# Получить результат поиска YouTube (без API)

Tags: search, youtube, youtube-api

На днях нашел сайт с удивительным функционалом.

Удивительное в нем то, что поиск мгновенно выдает подсказки youtube по событию нажатия клавиши.
Ответ вроде бы очевиден - `YouTube API v3`.
Но! API имеет ограничение в квотах, а здесь на сайте 4 млн. трафика / мес.
Соответственно квота давно бы испарилась.

**Вопрос #1:** каким образом можно получить такие подсказки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Продолжение еще более интригующее.
Ведь отправив запрос поиска - получаешь мгновенный результат.
Результат выводится быстрее, чем на самом YouTube.
*(конечно же понятно, что ютуб грузит скрипты, которые тормозят страницу, но все же)*

**Вопрос #2:** как получить результаты поиска с YouTube?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотреть примеры можно на сайте `https://getmp3.pro/`

Comment: *Соответственно квота давно бы испарилась.*
Нет, если платить. А вопрос ваш в чем? как делать парсинг : разработав программу по парсингу, ну или в ручную например

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Мы уже используем Selenium, но он требует 5-7 сек на прогрузку страницы.
Нам же нужны решения описанные выше.

Comment: Ну т.е. вместо анализа ответов от апи ютуба вы используете селениум и удивляетесь ответу в 7сек?) Ваш вопрос в чем?) Как сделать быстро? - через апи. Через платное с документацией или прикинувшись сайтом - просто затраты будут или на оплату специалистов, или на оплату открытого апи, выбирать только вам :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Вопросы четко описаны выше: "как получить #1 и #2 с такой же скоростью?". У getmp3 решение не через API.

Comment: В комментарии выше ответ - эмулировать работу сайта(не через селениум, а садится и разбираться какие параметры передаются для поиска самим сайтом(ютубом), искать самые быстрые ответы, оптимизировать поисковые запросы, кэшировать запросы и ответы к себе на сервер :) боюсь вам это мало чем поможет. Сейчас ваш вопрос напоминает студента который собирается сделать убийцу вов :) Ну и мне очень интересны причины вывода "они работают не через апи".. вот правда, крайне интересно как вам это удалось узнать, но не удалось узнать как именно :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Как вы и сказали, логично будет решить этот вопрос с помощью YouTube API. Но 1 запрос списка результатов съедает 100 / 10 000 ежедневных квот. Можно отправить запрос на увеличение квоты, но нам и 100 000 будет недостаточно. Поэтому стоит вопрос: Возможно есть какие готовые библиотеки?

Comment: Готовые библиотеки - есть, для скачивания и конвертации - youtube.dl, для поиска - getmp3 (*вы ведь понимаете что они не просто так пилили сайт чтоб подарить всем библиотеку?*). По поводу ваших ответов про апи - я вам уже говорил выше, у гугла есть возможность "покупать" запросы, так что те лимиты о которых вы говорите - просто способ монетизации самого гугла

Comment: Вот собственно и нашел подходящую библиотеку: https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search-without-api-key

Comment: Ну вот и отлично :) Прочитайте как с ней работать, сделайте развернутый ответ, сообществу будет полезно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ответ #1:** как получить поисковые подсказки (без API)?
Google позволяет давать запрос на поисковые подсказки: с открытым доступом и без API ключа. Результат получите в виде JSON.

Подсказки для YouTube:
`http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=no+copyright+music`
Подсказки для Google:
`http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=no+copyright+music`

*Подробнее: [«Youtube API автозаполнение поиска»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275365/youtube-api-search-auto-complete) и [«Где документация Google API подсказок?»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102878/where-is-the-documentation-for-the-google-suggest-api)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ответ #2:** как получить результаты поиска (без API)?
Как и предполагалось, существует библиотека для такого решения [«youtube-search-without-api-key»](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search-without-api-key)

На RunKit можно погонять примеры:
https://npm.runkit.com/youtube-search-without-api-key

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]